# Merging and transposing in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables:

[Table 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dMFv8.png)

SOP Number is unique per order. For the table above, INVO23935 is one order and INV023937 is another order, etc.

Each unique item in an order has its own line and there could be 1 or more of those items. For INVO23935, there are three item X  and one item Y. But other orders could have the same item. For example, order INV023948 has one item X. There are thousands of different items and new ones are constantly added.

The line column is unique to each line item on an order. It is incremented by 16384 for every line item.  However, I don’t need line for the final table but I thought it might be useful to create the final table. If it’s not, you can delete it.

This is just a snapshot of the table, which has thousands of rows.

[Table 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y2EBh.png)

Table 2 has one different column from table 1 and that is serial numbers. Only certain items have serial numbers and each serial number is unique even for the same item. For example, there are three item X in INV023935 and three different serial numbers for each X.However, some items won’t have serial numbers so it won’t show up in table 2. For example, Item N1 in INV023937 don’t have any serial numbers; hence, it will only show up in Table 1.

I would like to merge to two tables to look like this:

[New Table I want to Make](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c97nW.png)

There are thousands of rows and it’s constantly being updated so I can’t do this manually. I hope I can use SQL to create the table above.

I will really be grateful if you can help me with this!

Comment: Which DB? SQL Server or other?

Comment: Sorry this would be MS SQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would work for SQL Server to always show Table1 values, then show concatenated serial numbers from Table2 if available (or blank otherwise)

```
SELECT
    T1.[Date] AS [Document Date],
    T1.[SOP Number],
    T1.QTY,
    T1.Line AS [Line Item Sequence],
    T1.Item AS [Item Number],
    COALESCE(STUFF((
        SELECT ',' + T2.[Serial Number] AS [text()]
        FROM Table2 T2
        WHERE T1.[SOP Number] = T2.[SOP Number]
            AND T1.[Line] = T2.[Line]
            -- Any other join conditions (if item is also required or not)
        FOR XML PATH('')
        ), 1, 1, ''), '') AS [Serial Number]
FROM Table1 T1
```

Comment: Would this work for MS SQL? This looks like Oracle syntax, which I am not familiar with. But really thankful you answered :)

Comment: Yes, all MS SQL - `COALESCE` handles the null case of no serial number found, the `FOR XML PATH` and `[text()]` is a method for concatenating fields to comma-separated values, and `STUFF` is a string function to remove the first comma with the given parameters. All the methods are on MSDN.

Comment: Thanks! I am testing this out as we speak :)

Comment: IT WORKED! Bless your soul :) You can ignore this question but is there any way to reduce the space between the serial numbers? Right now it is really far apart : TSP1803L1108         ,TSP1803L1119

Comment: It is probably a space before or after. Perhaps wrap the serial number field with `RTRIM(LTRIM(...))`

Comment: Thank you again and sorry for the late response--was away for a week. I added "[SERLTNUM] = LTRIM(RTRIM([SERLTNUM]))" that but it did not work:                 
        COALESCE(STUFF((
        SELECT ',' + T2.[SERLTNUM] AS [text()]
        FROM SOP10201 T2
        WHERE T1.[SOP Number] = T2.[SOPNUMBE]
            AND T1.[Line Item Sequence] = T2.[LNITMSEQ]
   and [SERLTNUM] = LTRIM(RTRIM([SERLTNUM]))                             and [SERLTNUM] = LTRIM(RTRIM([SERLTNUM]))